# Surface integrals and normal vectors

Tags: calculus

I'm attempting this question and having trouble with it.

Compute the normal vector at (8,2) and use it to estimate the area of the small patch of the surface

$\vec{r}(u,v)=(u^2-v^2,u+v,u-v)$ defined by

$8 \leq u \leq 8.6$, $2 \leq v \leq 2.2$

**My attempt:**

I derived $\vec{r}$ in terms of $u$ and $v$ and took its cross product and plugged in $u=8$, $v=2$ giving me

$\vec{n}=\langle-2,12,20\rangle$.

I then plugged in u=8.6 and v=2.2 into $\vec{r}$ and took its dot product with $\vec{n}$ and added it to $\vec{r}$ at u=8 and v=2 dotted with $\vec{n}$.

I'm not sure where exactly I went wrong or if any of this is even correct. I'd appreciate any and all hints and feedback. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given surface:
$$\phi (u,v) = ({u^2} - {v^2},u + v,u - v)$$
The partials are:
$$\frac{{\partial \phi }}{{\partial u}}(u,v) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {2u} \\ 
  1 \\ 
  1 
\end{array}} \right),\frac{{\partial \phi }}{{\partial v}} = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  { - 2v} \\ 
  1 \\ 
  { - 1} 
\end{array}} \right)$$
For cross-product we get:
$$\frac{{\partial \phi }}{{\partial u}} \times \frac{{\partial \phi }}{{\partial v}}(u,v) = 2\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  { - 1} \\ 
  {u - v} \\ 
  {u + v} 
\end{array}} \right)$$
And at $$(8,2)$$
this is:
$$\frac{{\partial \phi }}{{\partial u}} \times \frac{{\partial \phi }}{{\partial v}}(8,2) = 2\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  { - 1} \\ 
  6 \\ 
  {10} 
\end{array}} \right)$$

With $du = \frac{6}{{10}}$ and $dv = \frac{2}{{10}}$ surface-volume is
$$\left\| {\frac{{\partial \phi }}{{\partial u}} \times \frac{{\partial \phi }}{{\partial v}}(8,2)} \right\|dudv = 2\sqrt {137} \frac{6}{{10}}\frac{2}{{10}} = \sqrt {137}  \cdot \frac{6}{{25}}$$

The whole area is given by:
$$\iint\limits_S {\left\| {\frac{{\partial \phi }}{{\partial u}} \times \frac{{\partial \phi }}{{\partial v}}(u,v)} \right\|dudv} = 2\iint\limits_S {\sqrt {{{\left( {u + v} \right)}^2} + {{\left( {u - v} \right)}^2} + 1}  \cdot dudv}$$
if lower and upper bounds are given. So we have to integrate the surface-volume element.

Comment: Hi Frieder,

I'm following what you did up to the last part where you set up the length of cross product. Can you please explain where that comes from? Thanks.

From what I can gather, the length of the cross product would give you area of the parallelogram given by the two vectors and you're multiplying it by the du and dv, which give you the "weight" that the question asks for. I might be misunderstanding something but I'm unable to see how that connects to the original question.

Edit: Never mind I think I understanding it now... Thanks again.

Comment: @AllenLee: Hey Allen.  You should estimate the area between this range:
$8 \leq u \leq 8.6$ and $2 \leq v \leq 2.2$. So we have to multiply with
du resp. dv. This gives the small area of surface, not only parallelogramm
build from tangent-vectors.